# Ansible AWX shows .cloud email as invalid

Tags: ansible, redhat, email-validation, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

I want to create a new user on my AWX server. If I enter an email adress with a .cloud domain (email@mydomain.cloud) the field is shown to contain an invalid email adress. If the adress is a .net for example (email@mydomain.net) everything is fine, so it seems there is a problem with the .cloud domain.

Is there a list or filter or something where i can add .cloud as a valid domain for emails?

Comment: AWX is a Django app and I would guess that the Django EmailValidator does not accept the `.cloud` domain...?

Comment: [This is where your problem comes from](https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/aa4ca300f51781028517397b259319293cd664f8/awx/ui_next/src/util/validators.jsx#L53) (taken from the latest released tag). It looks like [the validation has been lightened on the devel version](https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/4d21d699bb929721e333d9499177453cfa721074/awx/ui_next/src/util/validators.jsx#L48)

Comment: @Zeitounator thanks, so there is not much I can do right now?

Comment: You can build images from devel branch and try. You can also try to mess with the Dom/events with your navigator dev tool to drop the validation.

Comment: And alternatively, you can ask the question directly to the redhat dev team through the github issue page on their project.